# how to apply color to my axes in d3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am new to d3. I created an axes in d3 and its working fine but i can't set color to my axes. I tried `fill:none` but it doesn't work for me. Here is the jsfiddle link

```
http://jsfiddle.net/untnht4u/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can color your axis with CSS.
You can set class to the axis as shown below:

```
var xAxisGroup = svgContainer.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(xAxis);
```

and on the css add class

```
.axis path, .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: red;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
```

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/x80c3r41/2/)