# d3.js:Add color to axes dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

I am trying to create a line chart in d3.js.The color of the axes for this chart would be available only at runtime and can vary in a vast set of colors.It is possible to set the colors for the axes using css classes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32154943/3835632).

But since the range of colors that my chart can take is vast and only available at runtime, its not feasible to use this solution.Using `call(yAxis).style("stroke",userColor)` sets the color for the font use on axes labels and ticks but not the color of axis itself.

Is it possible to set the color of axis in d3.js axis dynamically using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the what you might want is something like the following:

```
d3.selectAll('.axis path')
    .style("stroke", userColor)
    .style("fill", userColor)
```

In this case, `.axis path` should be some identifying css on your axis lines (possibly put in with d3 as well in your `yAxis` function). You probably only need one of `fill` and `stroke`, try it out to see what works for you. This should operate on the actual axis line, rather than the text element

Comment: You got it right as t to what I want to achieve.I was wondering if d3 itself provides something to set axis color dynamically as it does for various other attributes.This would reduce the effort and simplify the code greatly.

Comment: It shouldn't have trouble with setting the axis color in that way, you can modify a selection dynamically. I'll see if I can find some examples, or if you create a plunkr/jsfiddle I might be able to help you modify it. The best way to do it might depend a little on how you want to trigger the change in color.

Comment: Seems like currently there is no better way of doing it.I finally followed this approach only.